# Can't assign variable to Google Analytics autolink

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have the following code inside a `twig` template:

```
<script>
    var test = { testKeyOne: 'some test one', testKeyTwo: 'some test two'};

    ga('create', '{{ analytics }}', 'auto', {'name': 'Name Here', 'allowLinker': true});
    ga('require', 'ec');
    ga('require', 'linker');
    ga('linker:autoLink', [test.testKeyOne, test.testKeyTwo]);
</script>
```

I want to put the values of `test` inside the line of `linker:autolink`.

The values that come from twig are showed normally, **but the values of `test` aren't being evaluated**, not coming as *some test one* or *some test two*, but as *test.testKeyOne* and *test.testKeyTwo*.

How to add the evaluated values from `js` to `ga('linker:autoLink', ...)` ?

Comment: You want the final result to be `ga('linker:autoLink', [some test one, some test two]);` ? Please add more details about the desired output.

Comment: @Nima exactly! I want the values of the variables, but they aren't being evaluated in execution time

Comment: I'm a little confused then. Add `console.log(test)` after the last line of code and the output in your browser console would be something like `{testKeyOne: "some test one", testKeyTwo: "some test two"}`, so this code is working. I can't figure out what the problem is then.

Comment: @Nima yes, I already tried this. When I put inside a `console.log` it shows me the value normally, but when I try to use this value inside `ga`, it's not considering the value, it simple shows me `test.testKeyOne, test.testKeyTwo`